# How to perform Conditional Formatting on the max value of a range of cells?

Tags: libreoffice-calc

i'm assuming what i'm trying to accomplish here is really simple, so bear with me here. i just want to create a Conditional Format on a row of cells and have it highlight (bold'ed) the maximum value, using LibreOffice Calc

Example

```
A  B  C  
3  4  7
```

i'd like to create a CF on A1:C1 and have C1 highlighted. i tried just doing a *Formula is* max(a1:c1) but it doesn't seem to work:(. in this case 7 would be formatted bold

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ah, got it, ended up needing to do something like `A1=MAX($A1:$C1)`

Comment: Not sure you actually got it.  That would give you a circular reference error.

Comment: For me, this works fine. You'll have to define the CF to cell A1 first, and then to paste format to the other cells.